# Symfony form ChoiceType is ignoring the required attribute

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony-3.3, symfony3.x

On a form I add a field like this

```
$builder->add('cse',
ChoiceType::class,
array(
    'label' => '',
    'required' => true,
    'translation_domain' => 'messages',
    'choices' => array(
        'I agree' => true
    ),
    'expanded' => true,
    'multiple' => true,
    'data' => null,
    'attr' => array( 'class' => 'form_f' ),
)
```

)

While all other fields added to the form that have 'required' set to 'true' will prevent the form from being send the required attribute for this field is ignored (the form is sent anyways no matter if checked or not).

Do I have to handle this with Assert statements? If yes - still: why is required not working here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use Assert.

Because `multiple=true` print `checkbox`. Html validator can test `radio`, but no `checkbox`.

**Always use Assert for all forms**, because html validator isn't safe :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I cannot use the asserts, and since was not possible to handle this in user side (unless you use javascript), I made the checks in server side, in the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` [hook](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit):

```
$builder->addEventListener(
    FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (FormEvent $event) {
        if ($field->required && !isset($event->getData()[$field->name])) {
            $event->getForm()->addError(new FormError('One option must be chosen on "' . $field->label . '"'));
        }
    });
```